# Can the brain get used to unbalanced hearing from treating unilateral hearing loss?

Tags: ear, noise-induce-hearing-harm, hearing-aids, hearing-loss

According to this imaginary example of unilateral hearing loss, if they treat just the weaker ear, it might create unbalanced hearing so that sounds heard by the treated ear are perceived as louder than those heard by the stronger ear.

[image]

In cases like this, the f, th, and s sounds coming from a talker cannot be heard from their impaired side according to the speech banana, and listening when there's background noise may be challenging.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_banana#/media/File:Speech_Banana_no_icons.png

They might decide to purchase only a single hearing aid for financial reasons.

If that's the case, would the loudness imbalance become less noticeable as the brain adapts? Would it affect sound localization?

In cases like this, would audiologists normally encourage their patient to treat their "healthy ear"?

Note that the "healthy ear" already has slight and mild hearing loss at certain frequencies, but its PTA is considered normal. In the real world, they may need the volume to be a little louder than someone with 0 dB of hearing loss would. Sounds heard from that ear may be perceived as a little muffled.

If only one hearing aid is worn, the unaided ear may get worse at speech discrimination. One question is how much hearing loss the unaided ear needs to have before this effect can happen. Can it happen if the hearing loss is less than 26 dB?
https://cdn.intechopen.com/pdfs/15121/InTech-Unilateral_versus_bilateral_hearing_aid_fittings.pdf

We should also consider what might happen in real life if they decide to treat only one ear. What if they listen to someone further away, turn down the loudspeakers, change their preferred ear if their treated ear is their non-dominant one, stop asking someone to speak louder or repeat what they said, or reduce their listening effort?

Comment: Treating things that don't need treatment is rarely a wise choice.

Comment: In the real world, it's sometimes hard to predict what will happen. What if the HA user deprives their "healthy ear" by sitting further away from their instructor, turning down the loudspeakers, or turning their corrected ear to someone speaking? I imagine that it might be easy to overcome the issue of unbalanced hearing while wearing one HA if there's only a little hearing loss at most or all of the frequencies in the "healthy ear".